# Fitting a laptop inside a pc case to improve cooling performance?

Tags: laptop, cooling

**Tl;Dr version:**

From my understanding, stripping off the plastic shell from the back of laptop, which would expose the heatsink and fan, and adding a couple of desktop fans pointing at the laptop heatsink *definitely should* improve thermal performance, to significantly reduce temps, correct?

**Non tl:Dr version**

Currently my cpu is pushing 75-80c under load (i3 2130m), and the laptop gets exceptionally hot when doing anything gpu intensive (7670m)- it just shuts off.

Ive just upgraded the laptop's ram and storage so I am not keen to give up on it just yet, as now it runs very well for a 2013 laptop, EXCEPT for overheating.

I am certain that it's an overheating issue since it's getting very warm under load and the fan spins up like crazy. It has been cleaned a few months ago so I know it's not just dust.

My idea is that getting a  pc case and a couple of big fans to cool it off would be much more efficient (and safer) than trying to repaste / add some custom heatsink to improve thermals.

I understand that putting it into a desktop case would mean I'll have to keep the laptop mostly in its shell unless I'd be prepared to drill custom standoffs for its motherboard.

I'll need to get a custom psu (like a mains to molex brick adapter) to drive the desktop fans as no psu will power on with just the fans attached to it (?). If my research is correct, most  psus require being plugged into a pc motherboard to work, unless you short the 24 pin connector (something that I am not prepared to do). Not to mention that a 10w load (2 fans) would be very inefficient for even a 400w psu.

My only concern is that I am overestimating the cooling abilities of such a setup and that it won't keep my overheating laptop cool enough to work under load. Is this a valid concern? Am I simply throwing money away (um, I mean, getting a pc case for my next build a little earlier).

Thanks

Edit: model number: hp envy m6 1232sa (build year 2013).

Specs (for completeness).
2x 512gb ssd
16gb ram
I3-2130m
Amd 7670m (2gb)

Comment: I've achieved big results from moving a desktops innards to a large (ATX/EATX) case, and adding additional fans, so yes, that can have a big impact. Whether its big enough or whether you have removed enough of the shell to make a difference is something we can't really estimate for you.

Comment: Have you thought about buying a new fan for the laptop? I had a laptop that used to overheat. The fan would run, but it was not hitting the correct RPM's when it would get hot. After replacing the fan, I had no problems.

Comment: For the **Tl;Dr version** Yes, increasing air flow thru the motherboard circuitry and components will definitely help them run cooler assuming the air is not hot of course. Be sure you've blown it out with some pressure to remove dust, etc. which could restrict the flow while powered off. Check to ensure it has not already gotten heat damage while the motherboard is exposed. Lastly, consider checking BIOS/UEFI settings to see if you can increase fan cooling speed in thermal settings and such.

Comment: Motherboard doesn't support any fan speed adjustments unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone does come across this and thinks it's an amazing idea...

Well it's not.

While it has "only" taken about 6 hours to transfer the guts from the laptop to the desktop case, there still exist some limitations, which aren't easily fixable.

I would say that unless you have recently upgraded your machine, it's not worth the trouble.

While it does run cooler there are quite a few issues:

1. Laptops have small heatsinks with small fin spacing, so adding a big 120mm fan doesn't actually help the Temps *that much*.
2. Many (most) laptops rely on outer casing to keep components together. Once you take it apart you run the risk that you can't easily transfer it into the case because of some proprietary ribbon cable

The pros

1. Idle Temps dropped about 20c off the bat, in the low 40s.
2. System is now inaudible in a fractal design define s.
   Can now run prime 95 without exceeding 70c,which is a breakthrough for this machine

Comment: Did you change the stock laptop fan to a desktop cooler kind?

Comment: Nope, I just attached the 120mm as close to the heat sink fan (which is at the bottom) and taped the sides, so you get as much airflow into the machine as possible. I wouldn't recommend changing the laptop cpu or gpu dedicated coolers - it's not worth the effort, as desktop heatsink mounts don't line up to laptop mounts at all, and laptop motherboards don't have any reinforcement to keep the motherboard from snapping in half if you attach a heavy motherboard (like a noctua for example).

Comment: Did you keep the stock fan on when you added the 120mm. I'm investigating this, because the stock fan is just too loud for where I'm keeping the laptop

Comment: i didnt risk removing the stock fan,as it could cause post errors on some (all?) laptops?